# Why did the writers highlight Arya's weapon when it was just a regular spear?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The special weapon of Arya in *Game of Thrones* season 8 was not so special, I think it was the same as an Unsullied's spear. So what was the point of that special weapon?

The weapon didn't do anything special in S8 E3. I want to know why the writers focused on it in previous episodes. **I'm not looking for technical info about that weapon.**

Comment: you should really split these into different questions

Comment: This will be closed as too broad since site policy allows only one question at a time. Take your time & ask questions separately. Be patient in asking each question, don't just flood the question timeline. Thanks

Comment: Only a few questions?

Comment: Okay, I updated my question and will post my other questions as separate questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Arya's weapon design?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/98377/what-is-aryas-weapon-design) - the answers don't cover S08E03 **yet**, but may be updated if/when that weapon gets used (S08E03 maybe?)

Comment: @Jenayah S8,E3 released and the weapon didn't gets used, that's why I asked this question!

Comment: @MehdiDehdghani well, in later episodes then :-) the answers based on future episodes would answer the earlier question, making it a duplicate.

Comment: Okay, if we can find answer of our questions in later episodes, what is the point of sites like movies.stackexchange.com then?

Comment: That's not against Stack Exchange's principles, far from it. A question gets asked, is thoroughly answered with what's currently available, and is afterwards updated and perfected with the release of new material. It fits the model and that's exactly what edits and new answers are for :-)

Comment: @Jenayah :-) ....

Comment: The premise of this question is incorrect, since the weapon *was* used by Arya.

Answer (score 5):

The weapon is used as intended. It was a detachable spear, with dragonglass edge on both sides.

When she's on the ramp, between two towers, she uses it as a spear like the Unsullied.

When she moves towards one of the towers & sees wights coming, she detaches the spear & it now becomes a dagger, one in each hand, which she uses to kill Wights.

She designed it to be detachable because the spear would be useless when moving through towers or close alleys & work only in wide open spaces.

It would be a handicap, so the spear was detachable into 2 daggers.

Answer (score 5):

Q: Why did the writers focus on Arya's weapon?

A: To build character.

The weapon was not intended to be a "save-the-day god-killer." The weapon was a way to show Gendry how much she had changed over the years, and to give her a reason to visit him at the forge other than chit chat. It was also a way to show the audience she's more than an assassin.